# Why US is supportive of YPG despite their links with PKK

Tags: united-states, terrorism, syria, middle-east, kurdistan

PKK has been engaged in many [terrorist activities](https://twitter.com/MousaAlomar/status/725701147781136384) and has been declared as terrorist organization by US herself.

Merely a month ago the US defense chief openly [admitted the links between PKK and YPG](http://aa.com.tr/en/world/us-defense-chief-admits-pyd-ypg-pkk-link/563332) and now they have started operation on Syrian ground with YPG. This is quite confusing to me, can someone please explain it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40618/discussion-on-question-by-talha-irfan-why-us-is-supportive-of-ypg-despite-their).

Answer (score 2):

Because ***there are no links*** between PKK and YPG.

The question as posed is non-sensical. It uses suggestive term "*links*" which isn't the actual reality (at least not reality based on the data you yourself use to support your statement, that is the statement by Ash Carter - or rather by Senator Graham).

> During testimony before a Senate panel, Ash Carter said "yes" when asked by Sen. Lindsey Graham whether the PYD and its military wing, the YPG, are **aligned** with the outlawed PKK terror group.

As it is, the US view seems to be:

- YPG is a Kurdish movement.
- There's **another unrelated** Kurdish movement (PKK) that happens to have similar goals and thus same alignment, but is (allegedly, and disputed) a terrorist one.

Their interests and end goals align - but that's the extent of their relationship as evidenced in the source.

As such, there's no reason for US not to support YPG - the fact that unrelated organization that shares similar goals resorts to terrorist tactics is 100% irrelevant.

The actual, direct answer as to "why" is "because they are the only ones around who are left to fight ISIL and aren't AQ offshoot", I guess. As Wikipedia notes:

> Even though the U.S. continued with providing effective close air support to the YPG, it also strictly adhered to a policy that sought to prevent the YPG from acquiring more independent military capabilities that could one day become dangerous to the U.S. ally, Turkey. **The U.S. started to deviate from this policy towards the YPG at about the same time as the dramatic elimination of its proxy the New Syrian Forces in September 2015**

P.S. Less relevantly, everyone supports someone terrorist-"aligned" entities according to the stated degree of "alignment", US included. US supports FATEH despite it sharing same goals as Hamas terrorists. Turkey itself - whose viewpoint this question is based on - openly supports Hamas in the first place. Most of American Irish supported and still do Sinn Fein, despite its alignment with IRA terrorists.

Comment: "there are no links between PKK and YPG." You haven't demonstrated this, and depending on what one means by "links" it is or may be false.